# Distance calculation Flutter background Location

Tags: flutter, location

I am trying to develop a Location service-based Distance calculation app. the problem is I need this to be run when the app is in the background as well. so I used the following plugin to do so.

https://pub.dev/packages/background_location

when this runs on AVD nothing happened but worked fine. but when run on some devices I got the wrong calculations. I have noticed that this happens when the app is in the background this is. following is a partial recreation of mine. I just want to know if my code get any error before posting this as an issue

```
   Future<void> startLocationUpdate() async {
  var permission = await Permission.locationAlways.isGranted;
  if (!permission) {
    var t = await Permission.locationAlways.request();
  }
  oldPosition2 = Location(
      longitude: currentPosition.longitude, latitude: currentPosition.latitude);
  isWaited = false;
  waitButtonText = "WAIT";
  BackgroundLocation.stopLocationService();
  BackgroundLocation.setAndroidConfiguration(2000);
  await BackgroundLocation.setAndroidNotification(
    title: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    message: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    icon: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  );
  //print('Inside startLocationUpdate');
  await BackgroundLocation.startLocationService(distanceFilter: 20);
  print('Inside startLocationUpdate 1');
  BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((location) {
    try {
      currentPosition = location;
      LatLng pos = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
      var rotation = MapKitHelper.getMarkerRotation(oldPosition2.latitude,
          oldPosition2.longitude, pos.latitude, pos.longitude);
      Marker movingMaker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('moving'),
        position: pos,
        icon: movingMarkerIcon,
        rotation: rotation,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Current Location'),
      );
      setState(() {
        CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition(target: pos, zoom: 17);
        rideMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cp));
        _markers.removeWhere((marker) => marker.markerId.value == 'moving');
        _markers.add(movingMaker);
        this.accuracy = location.accuracy.toStringAsFixed(0);
        totalSpeed = location.speed;
        totalDistance = totalDistance +
            CalDistance(oldPosition2 != null ? oldPosition2 : location,
                location, DistanceType.Kilometers);
        var totalDistanceAdj = totalDistance != 0 ? totalDistance : 1;
        //totalFare = 50 + (kmPrice * totalDistanceAdj);
        print("distance  $totalDistance");
      });
      oldPosition2 = location;
      updateTripDetails(location);
      Map locationMap = {
        'latitude': location.latitude.toString(),
        'longitude': location.longitude.toString(),
      };
      rideRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .reference()
          .child("rideRequest/${widget.tripDetails.rideID}");
      rideRef.child('driver_location').set(locationMap);
    } catch (e) {
      FirebaseService.logtoGPSData('Error in updates ${e}');
    }
  });
}
```

and the CalDistance method as follows

```
double CalDistance(Location pos1, Location pos2, DistanceType type) {
  print("pos1 : ${pos1.latitude} pos2: ${pos2.latitude}");
  double R = (type == DistanceType.Miles) ? 3960 : 6371;
  double dLat = this.toRadian(pos2.latitude - pos1.latitude);
  double dLon = this.toRadian(pos2.longitude - pos1.longitude);
  double a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) +
      cos(this.toRadian(pos1.latitude)) *
          cos(this.toRadian(pos2.latitude)) *
          sin(dLon / 2) *
          sin(dLon / 2);
  double c = 2 * asin(min(1, sqrt(a)));
  double d = R * c;
  //d = (d*80)/100;
  return d;
}

double toRadian(double val) {
  return (pi / 180) * val;
}
```

Any help or hint would be much appreciated

Comment: You need to calculate the distance between 2 points on the globe by longitude / lattitude?

Comment: I think that's what CalDistance method doing. and i simply need to know what's wrong with it